# How do I customize my 500.html error page? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I've done the following up to this point (see below code) and the 404.html.erb page works just fine! However, the 500 .html.erb page isn't loading for some reason it keep defaulting back to the 500.html page in the public folder. So I've deleted this 500.html file and now when there's an exception raised it's just a blank white screen.

What am I doing wrong? And why does the custom 404 page work?  (Using rails 4 btw)

See my code below:

**errors_controller.rb**

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def error_404
    @not_found_path = params[:not_found]
  end

  def error_500
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
...

unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, with: lambda { |exception| render_error 500, exception }
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, ActionController::UnknownController,   ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: lambda { |exception| render_error 404, exception }
end
...

private

  def render_error(status, exception)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: "errors/error_#{status}", layout: 'layouts/application', status: status }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: status }
      end
  end
```

**views/errors/error_404.html.erb:**

```
<div class="errorbox">
<h1><%= image_tag('errorimage.png') %>Oops! This page couldn't be found.</h1>

<p class="leftbox"><%= link_to 'Return to previous page', :back %></p>

<p><%= link_to 'Report a problem', contact_us_path %></p>

</div>
```

**views/errors/error_500.html.erb**

```
<div class="errorbox">
<h1><%= image_tag('errorimage.png') %>Oops! Something went wrong.</h1>

<p class="leftbox"><%= link_to 'Return to previous page', :back %></p>

<p><%= link_to 'Report a problem', contact_us_path %></p>

</div>
```

How can I get the custom 500.html.erb to be displayed when there's a server error?

Comment: You call `render template: "errors/error_#{status}"` in your application controller, and that matches the action names in the errors_controller, yet your view files are not named "error_404.html.erb" and "error_500.html.erb".  I don't see how either page is rendering correctly this way.  Maybe I've just had a long day.

Also, the line `format.all { render nothing: true, status: status ` in application_controller.rb is missing a `}` at the end.

Comment: 500 errors can happen outside of Rails... you may want to generate and cache these pages into public/500.html, etc. and configure your web server (nginx/apache) to use them...

Answer (score 0):

First write a error route in `routes.rb`

```
get "500", to "errors#error_500", code: "500"
```

then use the corresponding controller method and template to deal it.